# How to implement 'load more' on this page?

Tags: php, wordpress

Check out this page: http://goo.gl/mnG09W

Scroll down to the bottom of the page and look at the "Latest Feedback" section. See how it eventually gets long? And hopefully in time it will get even longer.

What I want is to display, say, 10 feedbacks, and then for the rest of them to have a "Load More" button or something like that.

Here is the code from that php file that is related to that bit:

```
                <div class="box_title_feedbk"><?php echo __("Latest Feedback",'PricerrTheme'); ?></div>
            <div class="box_content_feedcontz">

        <?php



                global $current_user;
                get_currentuserinfo();

                $the_id = get_the_ID();

                $pid = get_the_ID();
                $post = get_post(get_the_ID());
                $uid = $post->post_author;
                $author = get_userdata($uid);

                global $wpdb;
                $query = "select distinct *, ratings.id ratid from ".$wpdb->prefix."job_ratings ratings, ".$wpdb->prefix."job_orders orders, 
                ".$wpdb->prefix."posts posts where posts.ID=orders.pid AND posts.ID='$pid' AND 
                 ratings.awarded='1' AND orders.id=ratings.orderid AND posts.post_author='$uid' order by ratid desc limit 12";
                $r = $wpdb->get_results($query);

                if(count($r) > 0)
                {


                    foreach($r as $row)
                    {
                        $post = $row->pid;
                        $post = get_post($post);
                        $user = get_userdata($row->uid);

                        ?>

                        <div class="post" style="border:0" id="post-<?php echo $row->ratid; ?>">
                            <div class="padd10_only">
                            <div class="image_holder4">
                            <img width="25" height="25" border="0" src="<?php echo pricerrTheme_get_avatar($row->uid,25,25); ?>" />
                            </div>

                        <div class="title_holder4" >
                        <h2><a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/user-profile/<?php echo $user->user_login; ?>"><?php echo $user->user_login; ?></a> 
                        <span class="rating-beeing-done"><?php

                        $xx = current_time('timestamp',0) - $row->datemade;
                        $xx = PricerrTheme_prepare_seconds_to_words($xx);


                                echo sprintf(__("wrote %s ago",'PricerrTheme'), $xx); 



                         ?></span></h2>



                        <div class="c111"><p><?php

                        if($row->grade == 1) echo '<img style="float:left" src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/thup.png" border="0" /> &nbsp;';
                        if($row->grade == 0) echo '<img style="float:left" src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/thdown.jpg" border="0" /> &nbsp;';

                        ?>
                        <?php echo stripslashes($row->reason); ?></p>
                        </div>


                        </div> 



                        </div>
                        </div>


                        <?php

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    _e("The service doesn't have feedback yet.","PricerrTheme");    
                }
            ?>


        </div>
```

So I need that functionality implemented there. I'm assuming it should not be hard to do, but, I'm not sure.

Hope someone can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. You restrict the query for the first X entries that you want displayed, have a "Load More" link which then loads the next pagination step or shows all.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters
2. You hide all but the first X queries and then use a JS function to manipulate the DOM to show the rest.  http://code-tricks.com/jquery-read-more-less-example/
3. Utilize WP-REST API as a service to some JS/AJAX function to control and display the items.  http://wp-api.org/  https://css-tricks.com/using-the-wp-api-to-fetch-posts/

The answer to your question is really more involved than SO is designed for.  This answer should help point you in the right direction so you can learn what you need.